# UIWebView when switching through form fields sometimes the webview goes blank

Tags: ios, angularjs, uiwebview, ionic-framework

In the project I'm working on we're using Angular with Ionic. The issue I'm mentioning happens in a page with a bunch of form fields. When you switch through the form fields, at some point, the page goes blanc (the web page, not the view).

If I tap on the WebView, the keyboard gets dismissed and the HTML refreshes and displays again. It's kind of random. One has to be poking around, switching form field to field and at some point it happens.

Here's an example of what the input field looks like.

```
       <input ng-model="createAccountForm.email_value"
               id="email"
               name="email"
               type="email"
               value=""
               placeholder="{{translate('general.email')}}"
               set-aria-label="general.email"
               aria-required="true"
               required/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try switching to `WKWebView`, because Apple has encouraged us to do so itself.

> A WKWebView object displays interactive web content. New development should employ this class instead of the older UIWebView class.
>   Source: [WKWebView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/)

Comment: WKWebView does not allow cross origin on local files. I have local HTML files with ajax I need to load. This is on iOS 8, at least. I think there's a way on iOS 9, but I still have to support iOS 8.